# How to remove duplicates that have one extra letter?

Tags: python

I'm trying to clean my list of urls up. Some links are dublicates with just one extra letter in url(HTTP and HTTPS) ex. http://example.com/ and https://example.com/.
How do I remove them?

Comment: Did you got a right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Bendik Knapstad will replace all `http://` with `https://`.

In case you need to keep `http://` for not repeated urls you need a bit more complicated algorithm.

Something like this:

```
urllist = [
    'http://example1.com/',
    'https://example1.com/',
    'https://example2.com/',
    'http://example3.com/'
]


# make a dictionary where 'example...com/' are keys and 'http...' are values.
# dictionary can't have repeated keys

urls_dict = {}
for url in urllist:
    value, key = url.split(r'//')
    urls_dict[key] = value


# make a list from the dictionary

urls_list = []
for value, key, in zip(urls_dict.values(), urls_dict.keys()):
    urls_list.append(value + r'//' + key)


print(urls_list) 

# output 
# ['https://example1.com/', 'https://example2.com/', 'http://example3.com/']
```

Please note `http://example3.com/` isn't changed to `https://...`, because the original list doesn't have `https://example3.com`.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace one of them and return a set of the data

@druskacik pointed out that replace does not do inplace mutations it returnes a new string.

Its better to use a list comprehension as he sugests

```py
urllist = [url.replace("http://", "https://") for url in urllist]
#get unique urls
urllist = list(set(urllist))
```

Comment: Note that this code does not really modify `urllist` array. To do that, you can do e.g. `urllist = [url.replace("http://", "https://") for url in urllist]`